# Real time data map about the amount of a currency that are held in the world ?

Tags: macroeconomics, currency

Where can I see in real time data about the amount of a currency that is held in central banks (and maybe other significant  places) ? A map would be great.

I would like to know if there is an institution that watches where the currency reserves are held for the different currencies out there.

I would specialy like to know where is US dollar held around the world

I have another related question : knowing that oil and US dollar are directly correlated : can oil reserves be considered as US currency reserves in a certain way ?

I quickly tried the FMI website but did not find anything.

FYI : I'm just trying to get myself a personal point of view about the recent  dollar value raise, and I know peanuts about economics and finance : don't hesitate to prove me wrong :) .

Thanks,
Julian

Comment: Please ask different questions in different posts.